# Vue 3 Access to a DOM Element before mount

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3

I'm creating a Vue `<Link>` component inside NuxtJS with the new composition API syntax.
I would like to automatically set the `color` of my `UiIcon` when the root of the template has the `disabled` class.

I first thought to this approach, but then I realized that in the setup method, the DOM was not yet accessible. What could be another viable solution ?

PS: Managed to solve it using CSS `stroke` attribute because `UiIcon` is an SVG but I was curious if there as another solution utilizing the `color` pop already defined.

```
<template>
  <div ref="row" class="row">
    <UiIcon
      v-if="linkIcon"
      :type="linkIcon"
      :color="linkIconColor"
      class="icon"
    />
    <a
      class="link"
      :href="linkHref"
      :target="linkTarget"
      :rel="linkTarget === 'blank' ? 'noopener noreferrer' : null"
      @mouseover="linkActive = true"
      @mouseout="linkActive = false"
    >
      <slot></slot>
    </a>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import {
  defineComponent,
  computed,
  ref,
  toRefs,
} from '@nuxtjs/composition-api';
import { Colors } from '~/helpers/styles';

export default defineComponent({
  name: 'Link',
  props: {
    href: {
      type: String,
      default: undefined,
    },
    target: {
      type: String as () => '_blank' | '_self' | '_parent' | '_top',
      default: '_self',
    },
    icon: {
      type: String,
      default: undefined,
    },
    iconColor: {
      type: String,
      default: undefined,
    },
    iconHoverColor: {
      type: String,
      default: undefined,
    },
  },
  setup(props) {
    const { href, target, icon, iconHoverColor } = toRefs(props);
    const linkActive = ref(false);
    const row = ref<HTMLDivElement | null>(null);

    const linkIconColor = computed(() => {
      const linkDisabled = row.value?.classList.contains('disabled');

      if (linkDisabled) {
        return Colors.DARK_GREY;
      }
      if (linkActive.value && iconHoverColor.value) {
        return props.iconHoverColor;
      }
      return props.iconColor;
    });

    return {
      linkHref: href,
      linkTarget: target,
      linkIcon: icon,
      linkIconColor,
      linkActive,
    };
  },
});
</script>
```

Comment: Did you try `onBeforeMount`?

Comment: No, I didn't know this hook was for such use case!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [Vue documentation](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/options-lifecycle-hooks.html#beforeupdate) beforeUpdate is a good place to access DOM element before Updated hook. However you can also use $nextTick to access DOM inside beforeMount.

```
 beforeMount() {
  this.$nextTick(function () {
    //code here
  })
}
```

Comment: Sweet, is there a `this.$nextTick` equivalent with the Vue 3 `onBeforeMount`? From there I can update the computed property ?

Comment: yes you can use setup({ root }) {
   onBeforeMount(){root.$nextTick(function () {
    //code here
  })}
  }

Comment: The thing is the computed property is read-only so how could I modify it's value in here ?

Comment: Also, I get a deprecation warning on `context.root` which is apprently deprecated. Is there a new way to do in Vue 3 ?

Comment: You can use set and get methods of computed property as described here https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/reactivity-computed-watchers.html#computed-values

Comment: But inside `get/set` I can't use the DOM either so I have the same problem ? Could you share an example of what you're thinking about ?

Comment: For next tick you can import it directly from vue as described

here https://v3.vuejs.org/api/global-api.html#nexttick

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235879/discussion-between-theo-lavaux-and-atif-zia).